# Creating lambda function to create thumbnail for AWS s3 bucket is not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am learning using AWS lambda functions. What I am trying to do is, when I upload an image (JPEG) file to the s3 bucket, the image will be resized. But it is not working. See what I have done below.

I create a folder. Then created a node_modules folder inside the previously created folder. Then created a file called CreateThumbnail.js inside the main folder.

This is the CreateThumbnail.js:

```
// dependencies
var async = require('async');
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var gm = require('gm')
            .subClass({ imageMagick: true }); // Enable ImageMagick integration.
var util = require('util');

// constants
var MAX_WIDTH  = 100;
var MAX_HEIGHT = 100;

// get reference to S3 client 
var s3 = new AWS.S3();
 
exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
    // Read options from the event.
    console.log("Reading options from event:\n", util.inspect(event, {depth: 5}));
    var srcBucket = event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name;
    // Object key may have spaces or unicode non-ASCII characters.
    var srcKey    =
    decodeURIComponent(event.Records[0].s3.object.key.replace(/\+/g, " "));  
    var dstBucket = srcBucket + "resized";
    var dstKey    = "resized-" + srcKey;

    // Sanity check: validate that source and destination are different buckets.
    if (srcBucket == dstBucket) {
        callback("Source and destination buckets are the same.");
        return;
    }

    // Infer the image type.
    var typeMatch = srcKey.match(/\.([^.]*)$/);
    if (!typeMatch) {
        callback("Could not determine the image type.");
        return;
    }
    var imageType = typeMatch[1];
    if (imageType != "jpg" && imageType != "png") {
        callback('Unsupported image type: ${imageType}');
        return;
    }

    // Download the image from S3, transform, and upload to a different S3 bucket.
    async.waterfall([
        function download(next) {
            // Download the image from S3 into a buffer.
            s3.getObject({
                    Bucket: srcBucket,
                    Key: srcKey
                },
                next);
            },
        function transform(response, next) {
            gm(response.Body).size(function(err, size) {
                // Infer the scaling factor to avoid stretching the image unnaturally.
                var scalingFactor = Math.min(
                    MAX_WIDTH / size.width,
                    MAX_HEIGHT / size.height
                );
                var width  = scalingFactor * size.width;
                var height = scalingFactor * size.height;

                // Transform the image buffer in memory.
                this.resize(width, height)
                    .toBuffer(imageType, function(err, buffer) {
                        if (err) {
                            next(err);
                        } else {
                            next(null, response.ContentType, buffer);
                        }
                    });
            });
        },
        function upload(contentType, data, next) {
            // Stream the transformed image to a different S3 bucket.
            s3.putObject({
                    Bucket: dstBucket,
                    Key: dstKey,
                    Body: data,
                    ContentType: contentType
                },
                next);
            }
        ], function (err) {
            if (err) {
                console.error(
                    'Unable to resize ' + srcBucket + '/' + srcKey +
                    ' and upload to ' + dstBucket + '/' + dstKey +
                    ' due to an error: ' + err
                );
            } else {
                console.log(
                    'Successfully resized ' + srcBucket + '/' + srcKey +
                    ' and uploaded to ' + dstBucket + '/' + dstKey
                );
            }

            callback(null, "message");
        }
    );
};
```

Then I zipped the folder. Then I created a function in the AWS lambda console and upload the zip file from the UI as follow.

[image]

Then I added the s3 trigger as in the screenshot.

[image]

[image]

I also created the role with correct permission and policies.

[image]

[image]

But when I upload a JPG file to s3 bucket, it is neither resized not thumbnail is created. What could be wrong here?

This is the function policy:

[image]

Comment: don't you need to set read and write permissions on the s3 bucket since you are triggering a read when a new image is added to the bucket and a write when you put the thumbnail in?

Comment: Do you mean adding the policies to the role? I have updated the question. Please, check if that correct?

Comment: Can you check the function policy (by clicking on the key just above the s3 - in trigger snapshot)? S3 should have invokelambda access.

Comment: I just updated the question. Please check.

Comment: You can follow the steps from: [Tutorial: Using AWS Lambda with Amazon S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example.html)

Answer (score 1):

Lambda functions send their debug information to **Amazon CloudWatch Logs**. Examine the log file to determine what went wrong.

If there is no log, then either the Lambda function never executed, or the Lambda function was not given sufficient permissions to write to CloudWatch Logs.

See: [Accessing Amazon CloudWatch Logs for AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/monitoring-functions-logs.html)